# Database Modelling when multiple entities are involved

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have three entities in a MySQL based web application - Customer, Service and Note. Each customer can have multiple notes posted by different users. Similarly a Service can also have multiple notes. I would like to store all the notes in a single table for easy retrieval. Basically, there are lots of querying than insert/update to these tables.

The following is the database schema:

```
Table: Customer
id - integer
name - varchar
status - varchar

Table: Service
id - integer
name - varchar
status - varchar
price - float

Table: Note
id - integer
note - text
author - integer
type - varchar
cdate - datetime
```

I have prepared two approaches for establishing the relationship between these tables:

```
Approach #1
Table: CustomerNote
id - integer
customer_id - integer (References Customer table)
note_id - integer (References Note table)

Table: ServiceNote
id - integer
service_id - integer (References Service table)
note_id - integer (References Note table)
```

The second approach is to modify the Note table to save the Entity Name and ID of the record. This approach doesn't use the relations mentioned in approach #1

```
Approach #2
Table: Note
id - integer
note - text
author - integer
type - varchar
cdate - datetime
entity - varchar (possible values are Customer and Service)
entity_id - integer (related to id in the corresponding entity)
```

The second approach doesn't need any extra tables, but it's not easy to enforce foreign key relationship. As I said earlier, there are more querying than insert/update. So in that case which one would be more ideal and efficient approach?

I would also like to know if there are any performance issues if we implement a strict foreign key relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Second approach is better in anyways with an index added to type field. 
It will be better if you can convert type to an integer filed to represent these values . like 1 for Seevice and 2 for Customent. Will be faster if you use integer. But in any case, this approach will not satisfy your `enforce foreign key`.